# Can't install geany plugins

Tags: debian, geany

I want to add a plugin for lisp support to the geany, in the tutorial says i have to add the file.so to the /usr/lib/geany directory, but there is only a file named geany there. I have geany installed. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the so-file of the plugin to this folders as you can see from [documentation](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#plugins). It's ok to have it next to other files. Just call the .so in a reasonable way.

Geany will search also in other places as e.g. inside .config/geany inside your home. This is in special for developing or one-user-installation the better idea to place the plugin. This path is configurable.

When adding a new plugin have you read the [plugin docu inkl. howto](http://www.geany.org/manual/reference/) as well as screen the [hcking-file](http://geany.org/manual/hacking.html)? If not, good point to do so.